# Is the macOS Universal Clipboard secure?

Tags: passwords, password-management, macos, clipboard

Since the introduction of [Universal Clipboard](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25168?viewlocale=en_AP&locale=en_AP) on Apple's operating systems, I've found myself increasingly relying on it to paste passwords and authentication codes from my MacBook to my iPhone and vice-versa. I use a password manager, and on my work laptop, which is connected to my iCloud but doesn't have the same password manager installed, I often find myself copying the password on the iPhone and pasting it on the MacBook. In the case of two-factor authentication codes, the need is even bigger becasue I only have Google Authenticator on my iPhone.

Is it secure to do paste passwords using the Universal Clipboard (via Bluetooth, essentially) between an iPhone and a Mac or vice-versa?

Comment: I'm interested in an answer for the case of third-party eavesdropping in a public space - is UC safer than reading my 2FA code on one screen and typing it on another device?  Shoulder-surfing seems pretty trivially easy for 2FA stealing, given how slow numbers are to type.

Thought about asking this as a new question, but it seems to fall under this existing question.

Answer (score 2):

The specific encryption algorithm used by the Universal Clipboard feature has not been disclosed but I believe that all Bluetooth connections are encrypted (on some level) by default<sup>[1](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100554/is-bluetooth-4-0-traffic-encrypted-by-default-design)</sup>. Read this answer to learn a little more about possible attack vectors: [Is Bluetooth 4.0 traffic encrypted by default/design?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100554/is-bluetooth-4-0-traffic-encrypted-by-default-design). I don't know the exact implementation details of Universal Clipboard are but what I can say is that Universal Clipboard data is not uploaded to iCloud, it stays local to your devices<sup>[2](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/09/macos-10-12-sierra-the-ars-technica-review/4/#h3)</sup>. That means that Apple can't see what you are copying and pasting.

See also this answer to the same question when it was asked previously: [Universal clipboard iOS10 and macOS. How secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129834/universal-clipboard-ios10-and-macos-how-secure)

---

**Footnotes:**

1: [Is Bluetooth 4.0 traffic encrypted by default/design?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100554/is-bluetooth-4-0-traffic-encrypted-by-default-design)

2: http://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/09/macos-10-12-sierra-the-ars-technica-review/4/#h3

Comment: Also see the iOS 11 Security paper: https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

Answer (score -4):

No. Your Mac's CPU and your phone's SIM card are the critical low-level backdoors that render anything built on top of them(your clipboard) insecure. [So, even if Apple's closed-source clipboard isn't backdoored](https://theintercept.com/2015/03/10/ispy-cia-campaign-steal-apples-secrets/), there's two big reasons why it isn't secure:
1.[The Intel firmware has a powerful rootkit that you can't disable.](https://libreboot.org/faq/#intel)
2.[The SIM in your iPhone presents a gaping backdoor that's simpler and far cheaper for a non-state actor to utilize and take advantage of.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11550/how-to-spoof-a-cell-phone-tower-cell-site-base-station-homemade-imsi-catch)
 Nothing built on top of compromised firmware can be considered secure, so your clipboard never had a chance.

Comment: I fail to see how a SIM can compromise the entire OS. As far as I know the iPhone's modem does not share memory with the main CPU, so even if it's compromised by the SIM the main CPU is still safe.

Comment: You're basically saying that the firmware probably has backdoors so the clipboard isn't secure. That conclusion can be implied, but it's kind of a redundant point. It's like saying if Earth was destroyed then you won't ever have another cup of tea. Yeah sure, but then you'd have bigger problems. tl;dr keep your answers in scope

Comment: A9 Chipset does share Memory Space with iPhone's Internal Modem? Let's get the perspective here if it could be proven? I'm curious to know this.

Comment: If you follow American news at all, Apple was getting all kinds of publicity for not granting the FBI access to their backdoor in the A9.